# global name 'ssl' is not defined error while executing aws s3 cp command

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, openssl, aws-cli

Am trying to upload a file to the AWS S3 using the AWS CLI command.
I am using a system with RedHat 4 operating system.
Python version is 2.7.9
OpenSSL version is 0.9.8v 19 Apr 2012.

I have installed the AWS CLI and when I executed the below command I got an error regarding the ssl

> [test-user@redhat4 ~]$ aws s3 cp /export/home/test_dir/test_file.txt s3://test-bucket/ --region us-west-2
>
> upload failed: test_file.txt to s3://test-bucket/test_file.txt global name 'ssl' is not defined

Does I have to configure anything regarding the Openssl. Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue as am blocked with this issue for the last few days.

Comment: you can try something like `pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1`

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.8 is probably too old to interop with a modern server. It can be done, but you have to weaken the server's configuration, and Amazon is likely not doing it. That means your option is update OpenSSL to version 1.0.2 or 1.1.0.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: At 1st glance, it looks like an error in some _Python_ code. The _ssl_ module failed to import (for some reason? - _\_ssl.so_ could not load _libssl.so_ and/or _libcrypto.so_) but that error got somehow swallowed, and when the _ssl_ module was used it triggered the error. Or of course _ssl_ might refer to something totally different, which would invalidate what I stated before.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by installing Python again with SSL support.
I did it on old CentOS 5.1 server - but it will be the same for any other Linux distro. Also, you need Python 2.7.12 at least.

The example is for installing it in `opt` folder - you can change it. Thanks to sergey for the answer.

```
# install openssl-devel
yum -y install openssl-devel

# re-install python
cd /opt/Python-2.7.13
./configure --with-ssl  ### this line is the key 

make

make install

# re-install AWS 
cd /opt

/usr/local/bin/python2.7 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws

# you can make sure that python was installed with ssl support
# by running this command without error or messages.
python2.7 -c "import ssl"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar error when running aws-okta:

```
name 'ssl' is not defined
exit status 255
```

In my case the problem was that my python version and awscli versions were incompatible (see [Python version support matrix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/welcome-versions.html)).

Upgrading my awscli resolved the issue for me.