# aws cli commands - `fatal error: name 'ssl' is not defined`

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I am trying to serve my web app through an s3 bucket. I have done so successfully a matter of days ago but today, when running `aws s3 sync` I receive a fatal error that "name 'ssl' is not defined"

When I run with the `--debug` flag the ouput shows the error stemming from python in in my awscli version

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/awscli/1.15.40/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 157, in resolve_cert_reqs
res = getattr(ssl, candidate, None)
NameError: name 'ssl' is not defined
```

Curious if anyone has run into anything similar. I have referenced this post as well  [global name 'ssl' is not defined error while executing aws s3 cp command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121166/global-name-ssl-is-not-defined-error-while-executing-aws-s3-cp-command) but the solution provided did not do the trick for me.

**Versions**

- aws-cli/1.15.40
- Python/3.6.5
- Darwin/18.7.0
- botocore/1.10.40

Comment: pip uninstall awscli and brew install awscli - let the awscli manage the python dependency? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html

Comment: Simple as that. Not sure what happened in the past couple of days that got me in that state. Thank you, friend!